# How to print document to PDF on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to print documents to pdf](https://superuser.com/questions/568/how-to-print-documents-to-pdf)

Is there any open-sourced software that allows me to print directly to PDF from Windows7?

Comment: Answer to question:  http://superuser.com/questions/568/how-to-print-documents-to-pdf

Comment: Any particular document type, or do you want a print driver?

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/44701/creating-pdf-documents

Comment: I'm guessing a print driver is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

[CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp) isn't open source but it is freeware. It uses the open source [Ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) PS/PDF interpreter

Wikipedia article which may be of use: [List of PDF software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software)