# What is the best approach to make a pdf document?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, adobe-acrobat, export

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating PDF Documents](https://superuser.com/questions/44701/creating-pdf-documents)

Hi there.

I'm trying to make a PDF document, and so far I can note two things, if I make a document using Word and I try to export it to PDF, it doesn't work very well.

If I try to use Adobe Acrobat Professional to make a document, it works ok, but the editor per se sucks big time, IMO of course.

So, how do you make your own PDF documents? I'm using Word 2010 right now and I really like it, but I need to transform my file to a PDF one, if you know any way, it would be great.

Thx in advance.

Comment: This isn't a programming question so it's off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This question is possibly going to get closed (and possibly migrated to SuperUser) but can you clarify why the Word to PDF conversion "doesn't work very well"?  That is what I use, both personally and at work, and for my purposes it's just fine.  My Word documents have a variety of elements: links, tables, images, Visio diagrams.  It sometimes requires a little bit of work in Acrobat afterwards, but generally Word's PDF exporter seems to work well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating PDF Documents](http://superuser.com/questions/44701/creating-pdf-documents) / [How to Print documents to PDF](http://superuser.com/questions/568/how-to-print-documents-to-pdf)

Answer (score 7):

If you are able to make it in word just fine, then use a PDF printer driver, such as [bullzip](http://www.bullzip.com/) (freeware with limitations) or [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/) (Free/[GPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License)) and it will come out just like if you printed the document.

Comment: PDFCreator is one of the best and simplest methods to convert just about anything printable to pdf.

Answer (score 2):

Download OpenOffice. OpenOffice Writer has a built-in "export to PDF" function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a programming answer.

If you want to make a PDF from scratch, the best starting point is the [PDF reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) document from Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

If your not opposed to spending some money, we have used both Nitro (nitropdf.com) and bluebeam (bluebeam.com).  Both are great PDF making tools.  Both cost less than half of a copy of Acrobat Pro.  (which is why we migrated).  Bluebeam's markup tools are especially handy for putting comments, signatures, post it note like things on the pages.  Both have a 30 day trial as well.  Bluebeam (which i'm more familiar with) does not have its own editor that is very good, but it plugs directly into word, and makes wonderful PDF's. It also plugs into many other things, like AutoCad, which is much nicer than using the printer driver PDF converters.